# android layout 0dp shows Suspicious size error

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

this android xml code shows me error when i set `android:layout_width="0dp"` than its shows me error in linear layout

```
Error: Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible, probably intended for layout_height
```

I want to use an Edit Text view and a search Icon like this
[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16dp" />


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:src="@drawable/searchIcon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Error: Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible, probably
> intended for layout_height

**LinearLayout** is a view group that aligns all children in a single direction, **vertically or horizontally**. You can specify the layout direction with the `android:orientation` attribute.

For your problem, You should add **`addandroid:orientation="horizontal"`**  instead of `vertical`.

```
 <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

**FYI**

All children of a LinearLayout are stacked one after the other, so a vertical list will only have one child per row, no matter how wide they are, and a horizontal list will only be one row high (the height of the tallest child, plus padding)

Read official guide line about [**`Linear Layout`**](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

Answer (score 1):

Change  `android:layout_width="80dp"` to  `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:orientation="vertical"` to `android:orientation="horizontal"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:src="@drawable/searchIcon" />
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: when i change it to match_parent there is no space for search icon

Comment: @AnkurRohilla Change parent linearlayout width to "match_parent"..just copy my code nd try!

Comment: @AnkurRohilla what error u getting?which line?You can't use width as 80 dp for the design in question.You need to fit your views to full screen width..just think..

Comment: Error line : android:layout_width="0dp" 
**Error:**
`Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible, probably intended for layout_height`

Comment: @AnkurRohilla For that you should use android:orientation="horizontal".. Change android:layout_width="80dp" to android:layout_width="match_parent" and android:orientation="vertical" to android:orientation="horizontal" in parent layout..

Comment: @AnkurRohilla you yourself have written android:layout_width="match_parent" in the answer which you posted as resolved

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the error in this code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textField"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:src="@drawable/searchIcon" />


</LinearLayout>
```